# Change ejb3 webservice url in weblogic

Tags: web-services, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB3 session bean annotated with `@WebService(serviceName="MyServiceName", portName="MyPortName")`. When it is deployed into Weblogic 11g the service endpoint is located at

`host:port/BeanClassName/MyServiceName`

Is it possible to change the service endpoint address of the webservice? i.e. to

`host:port/my/context/root/something/MyServiceName`

I tried to use the weblogic-webservices.xml deployment descriptor, but it requires the webservices.xml descriptor which requires a WSDL location element, but that should be generated by the server and the location of it differs in the dev and prod environments.

Comment: One reason the above is useful is that in a Weblogic clustered environment, you can make a single entry in OHS (Oracle HTTP Server) and nest as many web services as needed under that entry. Example host:port/OHSEntry/BeanClassName/ServiceName. Otherwise, you need to make an OHS entry for each endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an EJB

```
package com.example;
@Stateless
@WebService
OrganizationService {...}
```

First you should write a webservices.xml file for it as follows, since its sections will be referenced back from weblogic-webservices.xml where the actual endpoint configuration is done.

webservices.xml (Caution: by adding webservices.xml webservice annotations in classes are overridden!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webservices xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2">
  <webservice-description>
  <!-- just a label, can be anything you want -->
  <webservice-description-name>MyServiceName</webservice-description-name>
  <port-component>
    <!-- just a label, can be anything you want -->
    <port-component-name>MyServicePort</port-component-name>
        <!-- Target namespace from wsdl -->
        <wsdl-port xmlns:ex="http://example.com/target/name/Space">ex:MyService</wsdl-port>
        <!-- Fully qualified class name of the ejb interface/bean providing the service -->
        <service-endpoint-interface>com.example.OrganizationService</service-endpoint-interface>
        <service-impl-bean>
        <!-- The class name of the bean providing the service -->
          <ejb-link>OrganizationService</ejb-link>
        </service-impl-bean>
    </port-component>
  </webservice-description>
</webservices>
```

Then in the weblogic-webservices.xml you can define whatever endpoint you want.

weblogic-webservices.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-webservices xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-webservices" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-webservices http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-webservices/1.0/weblogic-webservices.xsd">
  <webservice-description>
  <!-- This must match the name given in webservices.xml -->
   <webservice-description-name>MyServiceName</webservice-description-name>
   <webservice-type>JAXWS</webservice-type>
    <port-component>
     <!-- This must match the name given in webservices.xml -->
      <port-component-name>MyServicePort</port-component-name>
      <service-endpoint-address>
        <webservice-contextpath>/myContextPath</webservice-contextpath>
        <webservice-serviceuri>/myServiceURI</webservice-serviceuri>
      </service-endpoint-address>
    </port-component>
  </webservice-description>
</weblogic-webservices>
```

Comment: Above is almost complete, but it took [answer from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307201/set-contextpath-for-ejb3-webservice-on-weblogic-11g?rq=1) to make it work. You need to ensure targetNamespace=xxx in class WebService annotation matches namespace in webservices.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that adds another endpoint to the one generated from a JAX-WS web service by WebLogic.

I have a web service like this (simplified):

```
@WebService(name = "ClientService",
            portName = "ClientService",
            serviceName = "ClientService")
public class ClientWebService {

    @WebMethod
    public ExtClient findClientDetails(String ref) {
        // etc.
    }
 }
```

The WebLogic endpoint is `<context>/ClientService` but I want it to be `<context>/client/01`.

In `web.xml` I have:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/client/01</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now WebLogic offers the web service at both endpoints.

Specifying the URI in `web.xml` is needed because the JAX-WS library in WebLogic ignores endpoint specifications in `sun-jaxws.xml`. (In contrast, GlassFish only exposes enpoints that are specified in `sun-jaxws.xml`.)